# Installation getting stuck

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, system-installation

I am currently installing Ubuntu 14.04 from a DVD. I already had 12.04 and I chose to upgrade it.

The installation is stuck for some time now at "Saving installed packages..." and these are the last 2 lines in the terminal

(process:7467) GLib-CRITICAL **:g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(process:7993) GLib-CRITICAL **:g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

Any ideas on what I can do?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With full respect to Ubuntu developers effort, I would not recommend upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04. Instead, do clean install to avoid problems. Just do backup copy of your data, an then feel free to install fresh Ubuntu 14.04 erasing and re-partitioning whole disk.